# Exception when sending an email with play

Tags: playframework

iam getting the following error while sending an email from playframework 
sample code from Mail Notifier

```
        setFrom("xyz@xyz.com");
        setSubject("Relax 500 Error on production machine");        
        addRecipient("xyz@xyz.com");        
        send("errors/error1",errorContent);
```

if i use **error1.txt** everything is working fine **iam able to send email** .
But when ever i change the template to **error1.html** play is unable to send text/html messages for some reason which i could not able to figure it out.

Below is the exception :

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: "text/html" DataContentHandler requires String obje
ct, was given object of type class javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:625)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: "text/html" DataContentHandler requires String o
bject, was given object of type class javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
        at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.writeTo(text_plain.java:121)
        at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:86
9)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:302)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1350)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1683)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:585)
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Which SMTP server are you using?

I had a similar problem when using a Lotus Notes mailserver - and only in this case.  Every other mail server was fine.

The (somewhat annoying) solution was to copy Play's Mailer#send(Object... args) method and change

```
HtmlEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();
htmlEmail.setHtmlMsg(bodyHtml);
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(bodyText)) {
    htmlEmail.setTextMsg(bodyText);
}
email = htmlEmail;
```

to

```
public static Future<Boolean> sendMail(Map<String, Object> args) {
    ...
    HtmlEmail htmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();
    htmlEmail.setHtmlMsg(bodyHtml);
    htmlEmail.setContent(bodyHtml, "text/html"); // !! add this line!!
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(bodyText)) {
        htmlEmail.setTextMsg(bodyText);
    }
    email = htmlEmail;
    ...
}
```

Explicitly setting the content type of the htmlEmail object fixed the problem.  The side-effect of this was that we have to pass in a map of arguments that are explicitly defined in the mail-sending methods, e.g.

```
public static void sendTestMail(String to,
                                String subject,
                                String name) {
    addRecipient(to);
    setSubject(subject);

    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("name", name);

    sendMail(args);
}
```

In your custom sendMail method, you'll also need to change the code that binds the arguments, from

```
for (Object o : args) {
    List<String> names = LocalVariablesNamesTracer.getAllLocalVariableNames(o);
    for (String name : names) {
        templateHtmlBinding.put(name, o);
        templateTextBinding.put(name, o);
    }
}
```

to

```
for (String key : args.keySet()) {
    templateHtmlBinding.put(key,
                            args.get(key));
    templateTextBinding.put(key,
                            args.get(key));
}
```

Very annoying, and very verbose, but it works.

Comment: Thanks Steve i will change the code and see whether i can able to successfully resolve the issue or not.